# NodeJS sample code for Vonage text-to-speech outbound phone call?

Tags: node.js, text-to-speech

I'm trying to experiment with Vonage's outbound phone call using their NodeJS SDK.  To that end, I'm working through [their tutorial](https://learn.vonage.com/blog/2017/01/12/make-outbound-text-speech-phone-call-node-js-dr/).  However, all of the sample code they provide in the tutorial is missing: I only see black boxes, as below

[image]

I checked the source code of the page, and where the sample code should be there is only `...`, that is, an ellipsis.

Is this happening for you, or just for me?  I've tried three browsers, but same problem.

If it's happening for you, is there anything I can do about this, browser-side?  I can't think of a thing...but am keen to get the page to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for raising the missing code snippets on that blog post. The education team is looking into it now.

The [Vonage API Developer Portal](https://developer.vonage.com) has current up-to-date code snippets for making an outbound call using the Node.js SDK. You can find the link [here](https://developer.vonage.com/voice/voice-api/code-snippets/make-an-outbound-call-with-ncco/node) for making an outbound call with the instructions ("NCCO") or the link [here](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/code-snippets/make-an-outbound-call) for making an outbound call and providing a webhook to the API where it will fetch the NCCO instructions.